Best test for mortality rate in two countries
We’re trying to compare the mortality rate in two different countries over a period of 20 years. Is the Mann Whitney u test the best to use? We’re confused if the data is assumed to be normally distributed or not as the figures are simply numbers of deaths each year.

What are you trying to find out?  According to the CIA World Factbook Germany and Japan have roughly double the death rate per 1000 population (around 12) compared to  Ghana and Vietnam (around 6).  Presumably this is more an indicator of age distribution than anything else.

Mann Whitney Wilcoxon test is a nonparametric test so no underlying distribution is assumed.  i.e. useful for non normal data.

The Mann-Whitney U test (MWUt) can be used on normal, or non-normal data, equally well (in fact, MWUt works almost as well as t-test when the data is normal, and better when it is not).
Now, what the "best" test is depends on what you are tryng to prove.
The MWUt will tell you were to pick a random year from country1, and a random year from country2, the mortality rate from one country, would more often than noit, be larger than from the other country (stochastic superiority - not to be confused with stochastic dominance; what Mann & Whitney called "one population is stochastically greater than another). This is a property of full shapes of the 2 distributions (not just means, variances, etc.). If you test is significant, you can conclude that over the 20 years period country1 (e.g.) had higher mortality rates significantly more often. And yes, you can use it regardless normality of lack thereof.
You could also use the Mood's median test (Mmt). This basically ends up being a binomial test. As such, it has relatively low power. With sample size of 20 per group, I am afraid that it will not be powerful enough; depends on the data. Again, no assumption of normality is required.
Note that both the MWUt and the Mmt treat the data as ordinal. The size of the differences in mortality rates doesnot matter, only the direcxtion of that difference. There is some loss of information; no free lunch; that is the price for not needing any assumption on the population distributions.
You could also use a Welch t-test. This would compare the means. Here, there is a necessary condition; that the sampling distribution of the difference of the means be "sufficiently" normally distributed (normal-ish enough). But we have no access to this sampling distribution. So a sufficient condition is that both distributions be "sufficiently" normally distributed. The sample size of 20 per group is too small to confidently invoke the CLT. You need to look at your data to see how non-normal it may be; if e.g. the skew is large-ish (and it may well be positively skewed, or even bi-modal, e.g. because of spikes due to Covid), then a t-test may be ill advised.
I would run all 3 test, if only to ensure I get consistent results (it is possible to get country1 greater for MWUt, but the mean -pr median- greater for country2). But in the end, I would report only 1 result, depending on which "best" answers my question.
TL;DR: MWUt is fine. But there are other choices depending on what exactly you are trying to prove.

Doesn't the MWUt assume that the observations from both countries are independent of each other? Is that reasonable here?

Good point. Indeed it does. But so would pretty much all 2-sample tests (like Median or t-test), and even regression, etc. There could be correlations year to year in a given country (mortality trends should have low frequency variations): note that time-series measurements can always be suspected to have some autocorrelation. But less so between countries (they have different age pyramids, health care systems, eating/drinking/smoking habits, responses to Covid, etc.).  So, comparing the (possibly autocorrelated) rates in both countries still seems the most practical thing to do?
